# How to show ckeditor value on Asp.Net interface

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

I saved my htmlcontent from ckeditor textarea and I can't show this htmlcontent on webform.aspx.

[image: this is my interface code]

```
                    <div runat="server" id="aboutDiv">

                </div>
```

[image: this is codebehind]

```
if (reader.Read())
        {
            aboutDiv.InnerHtml = reader["KurumsalHakkimizda"].ToString();
        }
```

[image: this is userview]

Comment: Please convert the images to code.

Comment: datas saved in sqldatabase, when I took from database with asp.innerhtml property its looking like text string.

Comment: @Aristos any solution bro?

Comment: Is reader["KurumsalHakkimizda"].ToString() returning any value? Please debug. If it's returning value then what's the value.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur Thank you bro for your attention. As I said it was my fault. When I save the ckeditor value I have to save as value property to the database but I was saving the value as innerhtml. Thats why its not showing right htmlcode on interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need a text editor on your page, on witch the editor will put on. For example lets say that we have this **TextBox**. On code behind you get and set the text from `asp:textbox` very easy using the `.Text` parameter.

```
<asp:textbox id="txtDescription" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"/>
```

And second you need to initialize the ckeditor like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{
    if (typeof(CKEDITOR) != 'undefined')
    {
        var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( "<%=txtDescription.ClientID %>" ,
        {
              entities:false
            , enterMode: 2
            , shiftEnterMode: 1
            ,toolbar :
            [
                ['Maximize', 'Source'],
                ['Cut','Copy','PasteText'],
                    [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Superscript', 'TextColor', 'BGColor', 'FontSize'],                        
                    [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'HorizontalRule', 'Table'],
                ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList']                    
            ]        
            });
    else
    {
        // alert("you need to load the ckeditor");
    }
});
```

One more full page example for asp.net

```
<html lang="en">
    <head runat="server">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>A Simple Page with CKEditor 4</title>
        <!-- Make sure the path to CKEditor is correct. -->
        <script src="../ckeditor.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form" runat="server">
            <asp:textbox id="editor1" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server">This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor 4.</asp:textbox>
            <script>
                // Replace the <asp:textbox .../> with a CKEditor 4
                // instance, using default configuration.
                CKEDITOR.replace( '<%= editor1.ClientID %>' );
            </script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

base on [CKEditor 4 Quick Start Guide](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_installation.html)

Comment: @AristosThank you bro for your attention. As I said it was my fault. When I save the ckeditor value I have to save as textbox "value" property to the database but I was saving the value as innerhtml. Thats why its not showing right htmlcode on interface.

Answer (score 0):

When you save your data to database from **ckeditor textarea**,
You must send data as a string or value format in C#

at codebehind

like Textbox.Text or Textbox.value

When you show your data on webforms you must use InnerHtml property for divs, textareas or textboxs

Div.innerhtml = datareader["value"].tostring();